# disable jquery UI slider in a certain point

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

I have a jquery UI slider plugin in my website and it has total 10 points in which the slider can move around. For eg user can move the slider from 1 to 2 , 3 or 10  etc. I want the slider to disable in a certain point for eg I want to stop the slider if it goes on number 7. The rest point will be as normal. How can I do that? thanks

here is the html I am using to show the slider and numbers

```
  <div class="the_slider2">
                    <div id="slider2"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider2_bottom_txt">
                    <table >
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td >1</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td >3</td>
                                <td >4</td>
                                <td >5</td>
                                <td >6</td>
                                <td >7</td>
                                <td >8</td>
                                <td >9</td>
                                <td >10</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Here is the jquery I am using

```
var sliderAmountMap2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];



 $(function() {
    $( "#slider2" ).slider({
        value: 4, //array index of onload selected default value on slider, for example, 45000 in same array will be selected as default on load
        min: 0, //the values will be from 0 to array length-1
        max: sliderAmountMap2.length-1, //the max length, slider will snap until this point in equal width increments



});


});
```

Comment: what have you tried? The API docs have several event options you can use. Hard to really understand behavior you want. If I drag something to 7 and then it gets disabled what would I do?

Comment: if sliderAmountMap2 variable value is equal to 7 then i want to disable the slider

Comment: but that variable is an array. So that doesn't explain much

Comment: i have updated the full code i found in the plugin. thanks